# Beautiful Soup: Parsing "Span" element

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I keep running into walls, but feel like I'm close here.

HTML block being harvested:

```
        <div class="your-price">
            <span class="label">Your Price</span>
            <span class="currency">$369.99</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="price"  value="$369.99" />
        </div>
```

I would like to parse out the "$369.99" value alone (currency class).  Here is my logic so far, which captures both 'label' and 'currency' content:

```
r = requests.get(Base_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

product_price = soup.find("div", {"class": "your-price"})
print product_price.text
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either go down by the tree and search for the `span` with `class="currency"`:

```
print soup.find("div", class_="your-price").find("span", class_="currency").text
```

Or, use [`CSS selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) (at least, shorter and more readable):

```
print soup.select('div.your-price span.currency')[0].text
```